# How to resize columns from minimum width to auto resize

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, width

I have a spreadsheet with a number of sheets. The first sheet has X used columns and the remaining sheets have Y used columns. What I want to do is resize the columns between a given width and the auto-resize width if it is bigger.

So far I have the following code which auto-resizes the columns.

```
function resizeColumns() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  var lastColumnMain = sheets[0].getLastColumn();
  var lastColumnUniversities = sheets[1].getLastColumn();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var range;
    if (i == 0) {
      sheets[i].autoResizeColumns(1, lastColumnMain);
      range = sheets[i].getRange(1, 1, 1, lastColumnMain);
    } else {
      sheets[i].autoResizeColumns(1, lastColumnUniversities);
      range = sheets[i].getRange(1, 1, 1, lastColumnUniversities);
    }
    // Change width if less than 110 pixels
  }
}
```

I thought about using a range to somehow get the column width and then change from there if they were too small but I'm lacking the vision to see exactly how to do so.

Comment: `sheet.getColumnWidth(1)` will get the width of 1st column. `sheet.autoResizeColumns(startCol, numberOfCols)` will auto-resize cols starting from `startCol` and will resize `numberOfCols` from starting col. I don't see any use of range. To resize more than one cols manually to a particular width, I guess you'll have to use 1st function to get all the col widths one by one using a loop and then use the 2nd function to set a width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the answer to this one as well, and the following script is what I am currently using.
First  I created a dummy sheet with a header row exactly the same as the report I ran and set the columns to  the widths I wanted in each report . Then ran the following to get the widths of each column paired with it's index and push the values to an array , and set them in the row above the header as well.

```
    function colWidth() {
       var WidthArry = [];
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Setup'); //.getSheets()[0];
       var numColumns = 21; // sheet.getMaxColumns(); 
       var columnPosition, width;
       var i = 0;
         while (i < numColumns) {
           columnPosition = i + 1;
            Logger.log(columnPosition);
          width = sheet.getColumnWidth(columnPosition);
          //push position and width to array
           WidthArry.push([columnPosition, width]);
            //set width value in cell above header col see image
          sheet.getRange(1, columnPosition).setValue(width);
          Logger.log(columnPosition);
          i = i + 1;
        }
         Logger.log(WidthArry.toString());
        return WidthArry.toString();
         }//end function
```

Which returns the following  as well as setting the value in the 1st cell in each column of my header.  [set width value in cell above header cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDc8x.png)
`Logger.log([1,218,2,100,3,100,4,40,5,502,6,100,7,76,8,100,9,72,10,100,11,75,12,100,13,71,14,70,15,100,16,100,17,100,18,26,19,20,20,105,21,15, []])`

Because this report does not change as far as column widths, I just use each pair in a function call to reset the columns as soon as the data is parsed to the sheet.

```
    function SetWidth(e){
         var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
         var NwSht;
           Logger.log(e);
        if(!e){  return ss.toast("no event values");
          }else{
           NwSht = e;
            }
          var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(NwSht);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 218);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 100);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 100);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(4, 40);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(5, 502);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(6, 100);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(7, 76);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(8, 100);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(9, 72);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(10, 100);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(11, 75);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(12, 100);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(13, 71);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(14, 70);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(15, 100);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(16, 100);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(17, 100); 
              sheet.setColumnWidth(18, 26);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(19, 20);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(20, 105);
              sheet.setColumnWidth(21, 15);
           //setup toast to notify the task completed
          ss.toast("Column Widths Resized");
        }//end function
```

I am positive there is a more elegant way to do this, but I thought I would share for anyone else who was looking for a way to get and set column widths.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small function to apply autowidth to a sheet, but then extend any columns to a minium width if it's below a minimum value. It'll return an array of the new widths.

```
  // autosize, but with min widths
  setMinWidths(sheet, minColWidth) {
    
    // first autosize the columns
    const range = sheet.getDataRange()
    const columns = range.getNumColumns()
    sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, columns)

    // now ensure the widths are enough
    const getWidth = (_,i) => sheet.getColumnWidth(i+1)

    return Array.from ({length: columns},getWidth).map((width, i)=>{
      if (width < minColWidth) {
        sheet.setColumnWidth(i+1, minColWidth)
        return minColWidth
      }
      return width
    })
  },
```